# How to skip a link that won't open while scraping?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, iteration

I'm trying to write a .txt file for each article in the 'Capitalism' section on [this page](https://www.theschooloflife.com/thebookoflife/category/work/?index). But it stops after the 7th article, because the link to the 8th won't load. How do I skip it then?

```
res = session.get('https://www.theschooloflife.com/thebookoflife/category/work/?index')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
sections = soup.select('section ')
my_section = sections[7]

cat = my_section.select('.category_title')[0].text
titles = [title.text for title in my_section.select('.title')]
links = [link['href'] for link in my_section.select('ul.indexlist a')]

path = '{}'.format(cat)
os.mkdir(path)

for n,(title,link) in list(enumerate(zip(titles,links), start=1)):
    # ...and then I make a numbered .txt file containing the text found in each link. Image below.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided the most important parts: the exception that you are getting and the code which is responsible for url retrieval. Without that the only recommendation is to wrap your `for` body in exception, and continue your loop if any error, relevant to url retrieval occurs. Assuming that you are using requests library (as seen in `session.get`), you should end up with something like this:

```py
for n,(title,link) in list(enumerate(zip(titles,links), start=1)):
    try:
        # ...and then I make a numbered .txt file containing the text found in each link. Image below.
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        continue
```

`requests.exceptions.RequestException` is a general exception for requests module, you can find a more suiting one for your case here: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#errors-and-exceptions